# how to add serial number selected option value

Tags: php

I have a select dropdown with multiple select option value

```
foreach ($this->view->getallbacklogs as $key => $value) {
  echo $i;
  echo '<option value="'.$value['b_id'].'"data-position="'.$i.'">'.$value['i_description'].'</option>';
  $i++;
}
```

Which is working well. Is there any way to add a serial number before option value.

eg:

```
1 open
2 closed
```

etc.. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo '<option value="' . $value['b_id'] . '" data-position="'.$i.'">' . $i.' '.$value['i_description'] . '</option>';
```

you can concatenate the position with your value and just add a space between like an empty string. It will work for what you are trying to achieve.